# Inputting array problems

Tags: c++

Start of the program you need to input how many elements you want for example if selected 3 you can type a b c but if you input more than 3 elements a b c d the program instantly crashes.
Haven't figured out how to make if you input the more than 4 element a b c d it will only read the a b c part.

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    char teikums[100]; // Masiva lielums
    int c, i, count, patsk; // Patskani
    char yesno; // Atkartosanas Mainigais
    do {
        system("cls"); // Notira Ekranu
        patsk = 0; // Pieskir vertibu
        cout << "Ievadi Massiva lielumu 1-100: ";
        cin >> count;
        if (count > 100 || count < 1) {
            cout << "Massivs nedriklst but lielaks par 100 vai mazaks par 0";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Ievadi " << count << " burtus vienu pa vienam\n";
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

                cin >> teikums[i];
            }
            cout << "\nIzmantotie Patskani:";
            for (i = 0; teikums[i] != '\0'; i = i + 2) {
                if (teikums[i] == 'a' || teikums[i] == 'e' ||
                    teikums[i] == 'o' || teikums[i] == 'o' ||
                    teikums[i] == 'u' || teikums[i] == 'A' ||
                    teikums[i] == 'E' || teikums[i] == 'I' ||
                    teikums[i] == 'O' || teikums[i] == 'U') {
                    ++patsk;

                    cout << teikums[i];

                }

            }

            cout << "\nPatskanu Skaits: " << patsk;
        }
        cout << ("\nVai velaties atkartot(Y/cits):");
        // prasa lietotajam vai velas atkartot
        cin >> yesno;
        if (yesno == 'y' || yesno == 'Y') {
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (tolower(yesno) != 'n');
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)` and `for (i = 0; teikums[i] != '\0'; i = i + 2)` doesn't match. Also It seems that it will not crash even if the program ends  contrary to expected behavior.

Comment: one of `teikums[i] == 'o'` --> `teikums[i] == 'i'`

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` --> `#include <iostream>`

Comment: try [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) E.g `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` at after `for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                cin >> teikums[i];
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Your program will not behave as you expect if you enter in more numbers than your `count` because of how it is parsing the inputs.

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    cin >> teikums[i];
}
```

Let's say your `count` is 1, and you enter in `1 2`.
This will loop once and say `teikum[1]` to be 1, and `2` is still leftover waiting to be grabbed by an input stream.  Below that you have,

```
 cin >> yesno;
```

which will now set `yesno` to be `2` and your program will terminate because `2 != 'n'`.  You will need to either input the data correctly as your format expects or clear `cin` using something like `cin.ignore('\n')` which will ignore the current line of input.

Further, you start your `i` at 1 and go up to count but your array is only size 100.  If count is 100, it will try to access `teikum[100]` which will be out of bounds as your array goes from 0 - 99